# Size of a maximum matching <= Size of a minimum cover.

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

So I read that the size of a maximum matching <= the size of a minimum cover.
Could someone explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be *any* matching and $U$ *any* vertex cover.

For each edge $uv \in M$, at least one of $u,v$ is in $U$ or else the edge $uv$ is not covered by $U$.
Therefore, $|M| \leq |U|$.

It is easier to think of the size of any matching as a *lower bound* to any vertex cover :)

Comment: Ah I see... thanks